# How do you send Ctrl+Alt+Delete to Windows in VMWare Player

Tags: hotkeys, vmware-player

I run VMWare player 2.5.0-118166 from Ubuntu 8.10 using Gnome 2.24.1.

- I can find no menu options to send the combination to the welcome screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is being picked up by VMWare Player and releases input, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> can't be typed in directly.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should suppress VMWare Player from picking up the next keyboard input, but following this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> does not seem to work.

So I'm stuck, not able to log in to my Windows image.. **How can I send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to Windows within VMWare Player?**

Comment: someone has proposed closing this as a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/108109/ctrl-alt-delete-doesnt-unlock-pc-when-vmplayer-is-on , but i think that one should be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. In my experience with VMware products (Workstation and Server; I must say I have not tried Player, but I can't see any reason why it differs), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> only has special effects if you press and release them on their own, without an accompanying key.

Oh yes, I remember. It only works when the input is grabbed, or not (I can't remember which). Try grabbing/ungrabbing the input and doing that keystroke again.

---

Edit (gleaned from other answers; thanks!): If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> doesn't work, try:

- <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

VMware has some [really funky](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_devices_keymap_linux.html) [keyboard mapping](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws7_ace26/ws_user/ws_devices_keymap_vscan.html) [issues](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/177133) (at least on some versions, and at least on some platforms).

Comment: Don't work for me.  Maybe Gnome eats the key combination?

Comment: I can't remember if it requires input to be grabbed first, or ungrabbed. I don't have VMware working on my computer at the moment, but try both and see.

Comment: Both tried.  Neither works.

Comment: Soooo odd. Even the VMware person thinks C-A-I should work: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/23712

Answer (score 7):

After some more googling I finally found the solution.
It seems that the key combination is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print_Screen</kbd>.

It might be that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> works on other platforms.

Comment: Wow! That's bizarre! I'll favourite this post so I can refer people to it.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: Worked for me!  Note that I was remote desktoped into a computer which was then running vmware player.  Ctrl-Alt-End sent the ctrl-alt-del to the remote desktop, which caused both it and the VM to respond.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely works for VM Player: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>the period on the number pad</kbd>.
If you have a laptop without seperate number pad (as I do) then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> then <kbd>></kbd>

The host will take the focus as though it did not work, but after you click cancel you go back to the VNC session and it now displays the login prompt.

Comment: Great! This works for me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm RDPed into a VMWare Essentials host server and was having issues with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> because the cursor was released from the console.

If you're having this issue just click/focus back in the console and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>again.

If that doesn't work try Ctrl + Alt + End and you should be able to get to the logon screen.  This happened to me on a different VM.

Answer (score 2):

VMware has the menu bar at the top.  Select Virtual Machine, then in the drop down you will see the command - send Ctrl-Alt-Del

Comment: Doesn't work for fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I usually access my VMs via UltraVNC, which has a `CAD` (Control + Alt + Delete) button in its toolbar.

One mouse click sends the three-finger salute.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumDel</kbd> (the one that also acts as a period on the numpad) also works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (x64, 8.10) and VMWare Player 2.5: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> can be emulated as Jon and brian already answered:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumDel</kbd>

Don't release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys before pressing third one, or You will lose keyboard focus.

Answer (score 0):

Mind notebooks/keyboards with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> function for keys. Push it together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PR_SCREEN</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an XP VM in VMWare Player 2.5.1 on Vista 64bit via Remote Desktop.

The only one that worked for me was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.
It took me to the shutdown screen for Vista but when I cancelled that the VM was at the login dialog. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> first, not sure if that was vital or not.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print-Screen</kbd> works perfectly in Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Macbook Pro, there is no <kbd>Ins</kbd> key or <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>. Instead: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Does the trick to open up the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

USE EASE OF ACCESS ON THE VM SCREEN TO TURN ON THE OSK (On Screen Keyboard).

OMG finally figured it out - nothing above worked.....Windows 2012 R2 server copied a VM from site1 to site 2....NIC IP different so vSphere console will not open.

Used IE or Chrome to get to the console...but no option to press CTRL+ALT+DEL.

On the VM screen ==> LOWER LEFT corner ==> EASE OF ACCESS > on screen keyboard ==> CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Get that...you're using the OSK in the IE/Chrome window, NOT the host VM you're logged into, like you would IF you were using RDC.

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for keyboard shortcut for sending `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` for VMware Workstation 15 on Windows 10.  `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Insert` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The "Host" key is whatever is assigned in File / Preferences / Input / "Host Key Combination".  The default for Oracle VM VirtualBox (running Win7 in my case), is the "Right Ctrl" key.  So, the key sequence to unlock the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen would be RightCtrl+Del.

Comment: The question is about VMWare...