# Ctrl-Alt-Delete doesn't unlock PC when VMPlayer is on

Tags: vmware-player, ctrl-alt-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you send Ctrl+Alt+Delete to windows in VMWare Player](https://superuser.com/questions/106320/how-do-you-send-ctrlaltdelete-to-windows-in-vmware-player)

My desktop XP OS gets locked after I leave for x minutes. I have VMPlayer occupying full screen mode. I think the keyboard is redirected to VMWare.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and outer-machine XP is not unlocking.

I think maybe keyboard is going to VMWare, because this seems to only happen when I have VMWare running.

How do I unlock XP? Is there some magic key sequence?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/106320/how-do-you-send-ctrlaltdelete-to-windows-in-vmware-player ... while not an exact duplicate, the answers seem to address this situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

I think <kbd>F11</kbd> also takes it out of fullscreen mode

Also take a look at this other question:
[How do you send Ctrl+Alt+Delete to Windows in VMWare Player](https://superuser.com/questions/106320/how-do-you-send-ctrlaltdelete-to-windows-in-vmware-player)